# Deep copy of function arguments for polymorphic types

Tags: ada

I use an object based on a base package roughly defined as:

```ada
package Base is 
   type T_Base is abstract tagged null record;

   -- This performs a deep copy. Shallow copies may lead to STORAGE_ERROR.
   -- This shall be implemented by every derived type.
   function Copy (From : in T_Base) return T_Base'Class is abstract;
end package Base;
```

This package is derived by several packages which are further derived

```ada
package Foo is
   type T_Foo is new T_Base with record
      A_Data : Natural;  -- Of course, in the real code, these are types by far more complex.
   end record;

   procedure do_something (Foo_Object : in T_Foo);
   -- This implements the deep copy
   function Copy (From : in T_Foo) return T_Base'Class is abstract;
end package Foo;
```

On calling the procedure `do_something`, I do get a `storage_error`:

```ada
procedure handle_received_foo (Foo_In: in Foo.T_Foo) is
begin
   Foo.do_something (Foo_Object => Foo_In); -- The storage error does happen here.
end main;
```

When running the code with gdb, I get a segfault on entering the function and I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 39 (LWP 39)]
0x033c9828 in foo.do_something (foo_object=...) at ./foo.adb:67
67         procedure do_something (Foo_Object : in T_Foo);
(gdb) p foo_object
$1 (null)
```

So I guess I get a `storage_error` when doing the shallow copy of the argument `Foo_Object`.

I am aware that this is no MWE and that there might be a mistake in one of the types present used in the derived types.

I can't find any good option:

- Making `T_Foo` a `Controlled` type to call `Copy` in `Adjust` seems not to be possible without greatly changing its definition as I can't derive `T_Foo` both from `T_Base` and `Ada.Finalization.Controlled` since none of them is an interface types
- Defining `T_Base` as

  ```ada
  type T_Base is abstract new Ada.Finalization.Controlled with null record;
  ```

  and override `Adjust` here seems to induce a hell lot too much modifications on the existing code base as gnat yields in multiple places

  > type of aggregate has private ancestor "Controlled" must use extension aggregate.

So I'm low on solutions to either investigate the problem further or to solve it with a hammer.

Comment: How would you pass a T_FOO in to your main program? If main has a locally declared and correctly initialised T_FOO, does the do_something call work?

Comment: I get the T_FOO over the network. It is indeed not in my main program (sorry, shall have not called this main). T_Foo is far more complex than in the example. But I guess I could compare deep and shallow copies on this type and see if they yield a storage error.

Comment: I don’t see any calls to `Copy`. As it stands, it looks as though you’re passing `null` to `Foo.Do_Something` - not sure how that could happen

Comment: I might have been completely on false tracks. Working a bit on the code to study the copies moved the storage_error. I am considering the problem originating from a storage_size too small as, [per the doc](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_rm-docs/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/representation_clauses_and_pragmas.html#storage-size-clauses) "For tasks, the Storage_Size clause specifies the amount of space to be allocated for the task stack. This cannot be extended, and if the stack is exhausted, then Storage_Error will be raised (if stack checking is enabled). " In my case "-fstack-check" is enabled…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in the `Copy` function. The comments I saw in the code base were misleading.

The fact that introducing new variables changed the location of the exception made me consider some stack overflow problems.

Indeed the `Storage_Size` allocated for the task was not sufficient. Increasing the `pragma Storage_Size(<value>)` solved the problem.

Since the code base is compiled with `-fstack-check`, this led to the aforementioned `STORAGE_ERROR`.

More infos [on Adacore's documentation](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_rm-docs/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/representation_clauses_and_pragmas.html#storage-size-clauses).

This could probably have been seen with [Gem #95: Dynamic Stack Analysis in GNAT](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-93-gnat-dynamic-stack-analysis) but I am not currently able to see any result with the binding option suggested therein.

Comment: If you hadn't used `-fstack-check`, instead of `Storage_Error` you would likely see a segfault from the OS sooner than later. My worst memories are of tracking bugs resulting in either of those...

Comment: I agree that seeing the bug "earlier" thanks to `-fstack-check` makes the debugging easier. However, without being able to check the stack requirement with the `-u` binder option while gdb told me with `info tasks` that I have some 50 tasks running and no confidence in any of them creeps the hell out of me...